# How to send POST parameters from javascript to php

Tags: php, jquery

I have a problem with sending POST parameters from javascript to php page. All the script works fine, but I need POST params for further actions. In php $_POST array always turns out blank. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code so far:

HTML:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container" style="width:700px;">
        <label>Select Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
        <br /><br />
        <span id="uploaded_image"></span>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('change', '#file', function(){
    var name = document.getElementById("file").files[0].name;
    var form_data = new FormData();
    var ext = name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();

    if(jQuery.inArray(ext, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) == -1) {
        alert("Invalid Image File");
    }
    var oFReader = new FileReader();
    oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("file").files[0]);
    var f = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
    var fsize = f.size||f.fileSize;
    if(fsize > 2000000) {
        alert("Image File Size is very big");
    }
    else {
        form_data.append("file", f);
        $.ajax({
            url:"upload.php",
            method:"POST",
            data: form_data,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false, 
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('#uploaded_image').html("<label class='text-success'>Image Uploading...</label>");
            },
            success:function(data) {
                $('#uploaded_image').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

and PHP:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $errors = [];
    $extensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'pdf'];
    echo '$_FILES array: ';
    print_r(array_values($_FILES));
    echo '<br>';
    echo '$_POST array: ';
    print_r(array_values($_POST));
    echo '<br>';
}
// rest of code
}
```

Comment: I fixed your title. There's a big difference between Java and Javascript.

Comment: All your doing is sending a file. They don't show up in the `$_POST`-array. They are in the `$_FILES` array (which you also dump). What does that contain?

Comment: Thanks for your fix. I'm quite new in coding, so I have to learn a lot. Bellow is a little more details about my problem.

Answer (score 0):

please save below as file: upload.php inside http server (e.g. xampp) folder
then open on browser

```
<html> 
<body>

<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
        $errors = [];
        $extensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif', 'pdf'];
        echo '$_FILES array: ';
        print_r(array_values($_FILES));
        echo '<br>';
        echo '$_POST array: ';
        print_r(array_values($_POST));
        echo '<br>';
    }
    // rest of code
    }
?>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change', '#file', function(){
    var name = document.getElementById("file").files[0].name;
    var form_data = new FormData();
    var ext = name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();

    if(jQuery.inArray(ext, ['gif','png','jpg','jpeg']) == -1) {
        alert("Invalid Image File");
    }
    var oFReader = new FileReader();
    oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("file").files[0]);
    var f = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
    var fsize = f.size||f.fileSize;
    if(fsize > 2000000) {
        alert("Image File Size is very big");
    }
    else {
        form_data.append("file", f);
        $.ajax({
            url:"./upload.php",
            method:"POST",
            data: form_data,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false, 
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('#uploaded_image').html("<label class='text-success'>Image Uploading...</label>");
            },
            success:function(data) {
                $('#uploaded_image').html(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
});

</script>

    <div class="container" style="width:700px;">
        <label>Select Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
        <br /><br />
        <span id="uploaded_image"></span>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

it gives some details needed

```
Select Image 

$_FILES array: Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => zc.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php9437.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 17436 ) )
$_POST array: Array ( )
```